# move navigation items in opposite direction to mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar with list of list items(menu items). I would like to scroll the menu items in opposite to the mouse move i.e If I move the mouse in left direction on menu items the items should move right smoothly and vice versa. Do I need to write an algorithm with mouse events or this can be done with transformations please let me know.

I'm trying to replicate the nav functionality on this page https://www.bd.dk/produkter/kloak/broendgods/kuppelriste/oe315/222723000/city-kuppelrist-for-315mm-kegle

PFA the navigation bar

[Navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydSOd.png)

Comment: you'll need to be more specific. what's "mouse move" - you mean if you hover over a link or certain element or you just move the mouse anywhere on the page? and what exactly do you want to move and how do you want it to move (like how much/far should it move, should it stop moving at some point, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The mouse should hover anywhere on the nav bar and can be moved only till the first item. I'm replicating the functionality exactly on the navigation bar of this page. https://www.bd.dk/produkter/kloak/broendgods/kuppelriste/oe315/222723000/city-kuppelrist-for-315mm-kegle

Comment: Technically it could be done with css only and hover but it wouldn't be pretty.  Listenting for mousemove and changing some property is probably the way to go.  However I'm having trouble understanding what you mean.  Having items move around as the user moves to click on them sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: If you look at their code, they're just changing `transform: translateX()` by `0.8%` on `:hover`. Super simple. If you want help on here, you should post some code and what you've tried.

Comment: Yes I have seen that but unable to know how it is calculated. I will try writing some code.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated the translate as below

```
var posX = 0,
    navLinksContainer = $(".nav-links-bg"),
    navLinks = $(".nav-links"),
    navWidth = navLinks.width();

var widths = $.map($(".nav-links li"), function(e) {
    return $(e).outerWidth();
    }),
    totalWidth = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
    totalWidth += widths[i];
}
var transX = (totalWidth - navWidth)/navWidth*100;
if(transX<0)transX = 0;

navLinks.css({"transform":"translate(-"+transX+"%)"});

navLinksContainer.mousemove(function(e){
    posX = e.pageX - $(".nav-links-bg").offset().left;
    var newtransX = ((posX)/navWidth)*transX;
    navLinks.css({"transform":"translate(-"+newtransX+"%)"});

}).mouseout(function(e){
    navLinks.css({"transform":"translate(-"+transX+"%)"});
}).mouseenter(function(e){
    posX = e.pageX - $(".nav-links-bg").offset().left;
});
```